# How to enable remote connection for MySQL running in Windows 11?

Tags: mysql

I am having MySQL 8.0 Community Edition on Windows 11.
How I can enable remote connection to this MySQL?

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'StackOverflowSolution' WITH GRANT OPTION; 
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'StackOverflowSolution' WITH GRANT OPTION' at line 1
```

How to fix this error?

Please refer important [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/mysql-how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql) out here where I asked my question in comment. But they are more talking about MySQL 5.5 and older version of Windows. Lot has changed after that.